Deriving the Fahrenheit-to-Celsius formula from the Celsius-to-Fahrenheit formula
I performed a series of algebraic manipulations starting from the formula found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius, but I can't reach the correct Fahrenheit-to-Celsius formula. Where did I go wrong?
$$\begin{align*}
&x^\circ C = \left( \frac{9}{5} x + 32\right)^\circ F \\
&x^\circ C = \frac{9}{5} x^\circ F + 32^\circ F \\
&x^\circ C - 32^\circ F = \frac{9}{5} x^\circ F
\end{align*}$$

It would be best to think about the conversion of Celsius to Fahrenheit as follows:
If $x^\circ\text C$ is the equivalent to $y^\circ\text F$, then by the Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion formula:
$$y = \dfrac{9}{5}x + 32$$
Therefore, rearranging for $x$ yields the conversion formula of $y^\circ\text F$ to $x^\circ\text C$.
$$\dfrac{9}{5}x = y - 32 \Longrightarrow \boxed{\therefore x = \dfrac{5}{9}(y - 32)}$$

The wikipedia article that you referenced is accurate, but somewhat confusing.
I will use the variable $~c~$ to refer to temperature measured in Celsius degrees.
I will use the variable $~f~$ to refer to temperature measured in Fahrenheit degrees.
The statement $~x^\circ C \equiv \left[ ~\dfrac{9x}{5} + 32 ~\right]^\circ F~$ should actually be interpreted as
$$f = \frac{9c}{5} + 32  \implies f - 32 = \frac{9c}{5} \implies $$
$$(f - 32) \times \frac{5}{9} = \frac{9c}{5} \times \frac{5}{9} = c.$$
This corresponds to the wikipedia's statement that
$~x^\circ F \equiv \left[ ~(x - 32) \times \dfrac{5}{9} ~\right]^\circ C.$


I performed a series of algebraic manipulations starting from the formula found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius : $$x^\circ C \color\red= \left( \frac{9}{5} x + 32\right)^\circ F\tag1$$

You're misquoting Wikipedia: it actually asserts that $$x^\circ C ≅ \left( \frac{9}{5} x + 32\right)^\circ F,$$ where the symbol ≅ means corresponds to. (As a matter of fact, temperature conversion between Celsius and Fahrenheit is merely a bijection, i.e., one-to-one correspondence.) In other words: $\boxed{x\text{°C} ≅ y\text{°F}\quad\iff\quad y=1.8x+32\,}.\tag*{}$
Statement $(1)$ is incorrect, since it implies that $0\text{°C}\color\red=32\text{°F},\tag*{}$ which, by multiplying both sides, in turn implies that $0\text{°C}\color\red=212\text{°F}\quad!\tag*{}$
Instead of statement $(1)$'s wrong assertion of equality between corresponding Celsius and Fahrenheit temperatures (their non-equality is evidenced by the fact that the zero points of the Celsius and Fahrenheit scales don't coincide) $1\text{°C}\color\red=33.8\text{°F},\tag*{}$ we can equate temperature intervals instead: $\boxed{1\text{°C}=1.8\text{°F}}.\tag*{}$

but I can't reach the correct Fahrenheit-to-Celsius formula.

Yes, it's impossible to manipulate $(1)$ into
$$x^\circ F \color\red= \frac59\left(x - 32\right)^\circ C,\tag2$$ since no algebraic relationship exists between the units °C and °F (in contrast to, for example, metre = 39.37 inch).
Generally, if $U$ and $V$ are measurement units, then $$xU=f(x)V\quad\implies\\x\propto f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad U\propto V.$$
